# Number of weekdays between two dates applied to groups in a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, group-by, grouping, gapply

I am trying to use gapply on a grouped df to get a timeline for time entry on projects.

Below I want to get a column that will have available working time for a person based on working hours between the earliest date they booked time and the latest date they booked time.

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")
library("bizdays")
library("nlme")
```

```
time_df %>% dput()
structure(list(uID = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), hours = c(39, 
39, 39, 39, 19.5, 39, 31.2, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 31.2, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 31.2, 39, 39, 39, 31.2, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 15.6, 39, 39, 39, 23.4, 39, 39, 23.4, 3.9, 3.9, 31.2, 
7.8, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9), onset = structure(c(16090, 16111, 
16097, 16083, 16125, 16104, 16076, 16118, 16139, 16216, 16209, 
16181, 16167, 16160, 16174, 16188, 16146, 16153, 16265, 16251, 
16223, 16244, 16258, 16230, 16237, 16307, 16363, 16328, 16349, 
16314, 16335, 16321, 16356, 16391, 16384, 16370, 16398, 16412, 
16377, 16405, 16433, 16139, 16160, 16153, 16209, 16251, 16272, 
16230, 16342, 16314), class = "Date"), terminus = c("2014-01-24", 
"2014-02-14", "2014-01-31", "2014-01-17", "2014-02-28", "2014-02-07", 
"2014-01-10", "2014-02-21", "2014-03-14", "2014-05-30", "2014-05-23", 
"2014-04-25", "2014-04-11", "2014-04-04", "2014-04-18", "2014-05-02", 
"2014-03-21", "2014-03-28", "2014-07-18", "2014-07-04", "2014-06-06", 
"2014-06-27", "2014-07-11", "2014-06-13", "2014-06-20", "2014-08-29", 
"2014-10-24", "2014-09-19", "2014-10-10", "2014-09-05", "2014-09-26", 
"2014-09-12", "2014-10-17", "2014-11-21", "2014-11-14", "2014-10-31", 
"2014-11-28", "2014-12-12", "2014-11-07", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-31", 
"2014-03-14", "2014-04-04", "2014-03-28", "2014-05-23", "2014-07-04", 
"2014-07-25", "2014-06-13", "2014-10-03", "2014-09-05")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
#creating demo calendar to exclude weekends
create.calendar(name = "demo", weekdays = c("saturday","sunday"))

#function should calculate working hours between first time entry and last time entry
#ideally this will be applied to each group
timeentry = function(x){
  #creates an end_date variable from further end date in the group
  end_date = max(x$terminus)

  #creates a start_date from earliest start date in the group
  start_date = min(x$onset) 

  #returns weekdays between star and end 
  #then multiplies by 8 to get work hours
  start_date %>% bizdays(end_date, cal = "demo") * 8 
}

#group by uID and summarize
time_group = time_df %>% group_by(uID)
time_util = time_group %>% gapply(.,timeentry, which = c(onset,terminus))

Error in getGroups.data.frame(object, form, level) : 
  invalid formula for groups
```

I tested my function to make sure it works as expected.

```
> time_group %>% timeentry()
[1] 2056

> time_group$terminus %>% max()
[1] "2014-12-31"
> time_group$onset %>% min()
[1] "2014-01-06"

> bizdays("2014-01-06","2014-12-31",cal = "demo") * 8
[1] 1952
```

I don't understand how they can be giving different outputs.

I know there is something fundamental about gapply and the function I have written that I don't really understand. gapply documentation says I should get a dataframe output. I want to join that output with my original data so I can calculate utilization rates for people.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the packages that you are using to your question, and make it fully reproducible. I don't know where `gapply` is supposed to be coming from, and without `time_df` we can't reproduce your issue. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Have to anonymize the data first. I will post df and all other code relevant to reproduce shortly.

Comment: @Rory You can also provide some representative & minimal mock data, or the code to generate mock data.

Comment: In `bizdays` you seem to be using 13th Dec instead of 31st Dec :)

Comment: BTW aren't we looking for this? -
`library(dplyr);

create.calendar(name = "demo", weekdays = c("saturday","sunday"));

time_df %>%
  group_by(uID) %>%
  summarise(onset_earliest = min(onset),
            terminus_latest = max(terminus),
            working_time = bizdays(onset_earliest, terminus_latest, cal="demo") * 8)`

Comment: @Prem thanks for pointing that out. The calculation works just fine now. So that aspect of my function is not the problem.

Comment: @Prem you bring up a good point. I thought this should have fit into a summarize function instead but was not sure how to implement it and rather thought I needed gapply. I will try what you've proposed.

Comment: @Prem you're solution worked! However, I cant see a way to nominate your comment as the answer. I am new to this and either don't have the privilege or knowhow to wrap this post up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(bizdays)

#create calendar
create.calendar(name = "demo", weekdays = c("saturday","sunday"))

#calculate working hour
time_df %>% 
  group_by(uID) %>% 
  summarise(onset_earliest  = min(onset), 
            terminus_latest = max(terminus), 
            working_hour    = bizdays(onset_earliest, terminus_latest, cal="demo") * 8)
```

Output is

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
    uID onset_earliest terminus_latest working_hour
  <int> <date>         <chr>                  <dbl>
1     2 2014-01-06     2014-12-31              2056
2     5 2014-03-10     2014-10-03              1192
```

Preview of input data:

```
> head(time_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    uID hours onset      terminus  
  <int> <dbl> <date>     <chr>     
1     2  39   2014-01-20 2014-01-24
2     2  39   2014-02-10 2014-02-14
3     2  39   2014-01-27 2014-01-31
4     2  39   2014-01-13 2014-01-17
5     2  19.5 2014-02-24 2014-02-28
6     2  39   2014-02-03 2014-02-07
```